# How can I change the webcam that MPlayer uses?

Tags: command-line, webcam, screenshot, mplayer

I can use `mplayer -vo png -frames 1 tv://` to take a picture with my laptop's built-in webcam and save it to the hard drive.

I want MPlayer to use my USB webcam instead of the laptop's built-in webcam.

How can I do this? I could probably disable the built-in webcam, but I would prefer to not do so. Is there some kind of argument that I can give it, like `-webcam ID_OF_WEBCAM` ?

Comment: according to `man mplayer`, you can define the device like `device=<value>`, being `/dev/video0` the default. My guess will be that `/dev/video1` is you usb webcam.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not already installed, install the `v4l-utils` package

```
sudo apt install v4l-utils
```

Run `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` to see the webcam device e.g. `/dev/video2`. Here's my output (I have two web cameras):

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Cisco VTCamera3 (usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1

Integrated Camera: Integrated C (usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4):
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
```

Then run `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` so that you can choose a supported resolution and frame-rate e.g. `width=640:height=360:fps=15`

```
mplayer tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:device=/dev/video2:width=640:height=360:fps=15:outfmt=mjpeg -ontop -vf screenshot - geometry "99%:95%"
```